# Draggable component implementation with rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I moving implementation of draggable component from rxjs5 to 6. While testing i noticed that function onDragEnd is not called occasionally. What could be the reason for this ? Here is the code:

```
    fromEvent(this.ref,"mousedown")
        .pipe(
            filter(this.inside),
            debounceTime(300),
            tap((event) => { 
                this.onDragStart(event); 
            }),
            exhaustMap(() => 
                fromEvent(document.body,"mousemove")
                .pipe(
                    takeUntil(
                        fromEvent(document.body,"mouseup")
                        .pipe(tap(this.onDragEnd)) // <--- my problem
                    )
                ) 
            )
        ) 
        .subscribe( 
            (event) => { 
                this.onDragMove(event);
            },
            this.onError
        )
```

Edit: just to clarify what i expect, mousedown event should be map to observable which (assuming i understood exhaustMap correctly) should not allow to outer observable emit again until inner observable completes. What i cant understand is why in one of 20-30 times onDragEnd is not fired, observable from document so as my intuition telling me mouse-up is inevitable in this case, am i wrong ? If you have some ideas what could possibly be wrong with this implementation please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Can't you invoke `onDragEnd` in a completion handler in your subscribe call?

Comment: Thanks for response Oliver, i thought about this but i need to obtain last event value and it seems like onComplete does not recevive any arguments, i probably can preserve last event data in some outer variable but i thought to make it sort of "more dynamic" without need for this

Comment: Makes sense. I assumed that `this.onDragMove` stores the value(s). One possible problem is that your `mouseup` event handler is attached to `document.body`. The body may cover only a part of the browser window, so when you release the button outside the actual body you don't catch the event.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, will check this possibility